# RosJava and Eclipse

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys!

I'm trying to run a java example interacting with ROS and from Eclipse. I followed this steps (http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava/TutorialsRun%20a%20ROS%20Android%20example%20project), and particularly when I type 'rosmake android_tutorial_camera' the output worked, but no .project and .classpath file is created, and hence I can not import the android_tutorial_camera project into Eclipse. Has somebody any idea of this?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52966/rosjava-and-eclipse/) by [biyonder](https://answers.ros.org/users/1155/biyonder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-01-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2013-02-19**:
rosjava does not support rosmake. The tutorial you're referencing is horribly out of date and I've deleted it. See http://ros.org/wiki/android_core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> But still can't put into operation for higher version android 'android_honeycomd_mr2' ...

Really?
Now I can use both 'android_gingerbread_mr1' and 'android_honeycomb_mr2' libraries on eclipse.

---

Originally posted by [KazutoMurase](https://answers.ros.org/users/2505/kazutomurase/) with karma: 116 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LeopoldPodmolík](https://answers.ros.org/users/3844/leopoldpodmol%C3%ADk/) on 2013-02-13**:
Sry ,  now is working because both use same jar files , so when I choose only one as library and masterchooser.jar add to build path every think is now okey ;-)